# Update single field in base64 in whole table with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, base64

I have a mySQL DB defined with one table that has lots of fields.

Is there an all in one PDO statement I could execute to do the following  :

I want to base64_encode one field (field called cstat) in every single record in the DB.

Any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATE :

Thanks to TheEwook getting me on the right track and some further searching I finally solved it like this (I have a unique autoincrement field called record_id) :

```
  $sth = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM myTable");
  $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    while($row = $sth->fetch()) {

        $cstat = base64_encode($row['cstat']);

        $sql="UPDATE myTable SET cstat = :cstat WHERE record_id = :record_id";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);                                 
        $stmt->bindParam(':cstat', $cstat, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':record_id', $row['record_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple update query will suffice

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE myTable SET cstat = TO_BASE64(cstat)');
$sth->execute();
```

Or if you are using a mySQL version prior to 5.6.1

```
$sth = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM myTable");
$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while($row = $sth->fetch()) {
    $cstat = base64_encode($row['cstat']);
    $sth2 = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE myTable SET cstat = ?');
    $sth2->execute(array($cstat));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't appear to have worked.   I put it in a try catch block and it didn't throw any errors.  Also no PHP errors in log.

I then tried a version of the query using phpMyAdmin and I get the following error :

#1305 - FUNCTION custdata_db.TO_BASE64 does not exist

Comment: Can you tell me the version of MySQL you are using?

Comment: Just checked with phpinfo() and it returns :  5.1.71 and also just read that the base_64 functions were added in 5.6

Comment: This function was added in MySQL 5.6.1. That's why you can't use it with your current version of MySQL.

Comment: Upgrading MySQL isn't an option at the moment - can you think of another way I could do this please ?

I guess a way would be to have a loop that walks through the DB in php and changes each field but I just can't figure it out (I am new to PDO and MySQL) - Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Just editing my answer with an alternative. I haven't tested it but I'm sure you'll get the idea. Use base64_encode() php function instead. Let me know if there is any mistake in my answer.

Comment: That code just set the values of egmins to blank :)  (I had a backup lol).

I think it must be something in the UPDATE statement ?

Worth noting that if I echo $cstat it does contain the correct encoded data on each iteration.